# How to enable and disable the done button in keyboard in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

in my react-native App for the text input I want to enable/disable the done button on the keyboard dynamically. tried with **enablesReturnKeyAutomatically** but no use because these allowing to disable the done button only when there is no text in the input. here I want to enable/disable dynamically. can anyone give me some suggestions to resolve it. any help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import React from "react";
    import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput,Button,Keyboard } from "react-native";
    
    const UselessTextInput = () => {
      const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("Useless Text");
      const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null);
    const [done,setDone]=React.useState(false)
      return (
        <SafeAreaView>
         
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={done}
            onChangeText={onChangeNumber}
            value={number}
            placeholder="useless placeholder"
          />
          <Button title={'Toggle Done'} onPress={()=>{Keyboard.dismiss();setDone(!done)}}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      input: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
      },
    });
    
    export default UselessTextInput;
```

Comment: this is to dismiss the keyboard, but I want to disable the return button on the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not reliably.  The keyboard in Android is a separate app (actually one of any number of apps, as they can be replaced by the OEM or the user).  It decides what keys are shown, and what each key does.  You can give it hints, but nothing can force it to obey those hints.  If the keyboard app decides it wants to show a return key, it will.  And most keyboard apps show a return key if they aren't explicitly told to display an action key via the hints (such as Done, Next, Search, etc).  I don't know of any that would just make it a non-functional or disappearing key.

The Android keyboard interface really doesn't work well for dynamically changing the key while the keyboard is already up.  Some keyboards may work with it, but many won't.  Many don't as an explicit choice unless the focused text view changes.  There's some good reasons for this from a keyboard developer's point of view.

Basically if you're looking for some really specific behavior out of the keyboard, you're probably not going to get it.  Or you'll find some way to make it work on the keyboard on your test device, but it will fail on others.  And doing it in React Native will be even harder, because their method of doing keyboard stuff doesn't map well to how Android actually does keyboard stuff.